# How to measure each core CPU utilization/load (in %) in Micromax C4, using adb command?

Tags: android, cpu-usage

I am trying to measure CPU utilization for each core (in %) in a Micromax C4 device. I am unable to find the `cpu_utilization` file in `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq`.

Does anyone have any idea how to find the `cpu_utilization` file in C4, or any relevant file which would provide percent CPU utilization for each core?

> > > Waiting for response.
> > >       Any input from anyone???

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if there is any file which will be able to directly report the percentage CPU utilization but you can use /proc/stat to calculate the CPU utilization.

**adb shell cat /proc/stat** gives the following output

---

cpu  22251 758 19056 1170320 2786 0 243

cpu0 13628 401 14782 275769 1645 0 237

cpu1 4712 147 2394 295111 622 0 5

cpu2 2451 116 1149 298977 291 0 1

cpu3 1460 94 731 300463 228 0 0

intr 724661 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 184059 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 337 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 14401 0 0 21902 0 0 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 48850 175 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2901 16819 5708 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 8879 0 31124 0 0 0 0 5431 0 579 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 15043 0 0 0 0 0 6644 328 13085 0 6779 0 70695 1279 47348 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 6290 0 890 0 0 0 0 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 16846 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 10519 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3158 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 9 0 0 0 0 72 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5487 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 8818 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 6245 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2476 0 0 0 28 0 0 0 0 5 22 39 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

ctxt 1806341

btime 1378286111

processes 8249

procs_running 3

procs_blocked 0

softirq 323561 207 115027 207 2024 207 207 56793 19244 45 129600

---

first five lines are of interest. The first line represents the total time spent by all of the cores in different operating modes **since boot** and it is the aggregate of lines (cpu0/cpu1/cpu2/cpu3). The lines after the first correspond to the time spents in different modes by individual cores.

The meanings of the columns are as follows, from left to right:

user: normal processes executing in user mode

nice: niced processes executing in user mode

system: processes executing in kernel mode

idle: twiddling thumbs

iowait: waiting for I/O to complete

irq: servicing interrupts

softirq: servicing softirqs

Now CPU Utilization since boot = (user + nice + system +iowait + irq + softirq) / (user + nice + system +iowait + irq + softirq + idle)

Check this aswell: http://www.linuxhowtos.org/System/procstat.htm